# Notations related to identities for spinors in the rest frame

Tags: notation, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

This question pertains to some notation in Zee's QFT book, Section II.2.  The Dirac equation is

$$ (i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi(x)=0, $$

which we can write in momentum space with the Fourier transform

$$ \psi(x)=\int\!\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}e^{-ipx}\psi(p)$$

as

\begin{align}
      (i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\int\!\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}e^{-ipx}\psi(p)&=0\\
\int\!\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}(\gamma^\mu p_\mu-m)e^{-ipx}\psi(p)&=0\\[8pt]
\implies(\gamma^\mu p_\mu-m)\psi(p)&=0,
\end{align}

which is the Dirac equation in momentum space.  In the rest frame, $p_i=0$ and $p_0=m$ so we have

$$  (\gamma^\mu p_\mu-m)\psi(p)=(\gamma^0p_0+\gamma^ip_i-m)\psi(p) =0\quad\implies\quad(\gamma^0-1)\psi(p)=0.$$  For two Dirac bispinors $u$ and $v$, the solutions are

$$\psi(p)=u(p,s)e^{-ipx}~~,\quad\text{and}\qquad \psi(p)=v(p,s)e^{ipx}.$$

We define $\bar u=u^\dagger\gamma^0$ and $\bar v=v^\dagger\gamma^0$, with dagger denoting the conjugate transpose, to form Lorentz invariants $\bar uu$ and $\bar vv$.  ***Now I have gotten to my question.***   Zee gives a rest frame identity

$$ \sum_s u_\alpha(p,s)\bar u_\beta(p,s)=\left( \begin{matrix}  1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{matrix}  \right)_{\!\alpha\beta}.  $$

If it's not the spin $s$, which it is clearly not, then what do the $\alpha,\beta$ subscripts refer to?  Is it two discrete positions $\alpha$ and $\beta$?  What is the meaning of the subscript $\alpha\beta$ on the matrix?  Does that turn it into a Kronecker matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The expression in a general frame is
$$
\frac 1{2m}(m+p_\mu \gamma^\mu)= \sum_{s=\pm} u(p,s)\bar u(p,s)
$$
where
$$
u(p,s)= \left[\matrix{u(p,s)_1\cr u(p,s)_2\cr u(p,s)_3\cr u(p,s)_4}\right], \\ \bar u(p,s)=[ \bar u(p,s)_1, \bar u(p,s)_2, \bar u(p,s)_3,  \bar u(p,s)_4 ],
$$
so
$
u \bar u$ is a 4-by-4 matrix just like the $\gamma$'s.

Comment: What does the $\alpha\beta$ subscript on the matrix mean?  This was the major thrust of my question, thanks.

Comment: It means that the $\alpha, \beta$ entry in the 4-by4 matrix $u\bar u$  is the $\alpha,\beta$ entry in the 4-by-4matrix (m+\gamma^\mu p_\mu)/2m$

Comment: So that notation is completely irrelevant and redundant because we already know that's true for two matrices that are equal to each other?

Answer (score 0):

> What do the $\alpha,\beta$ subscripts refer to?

On $u_\alpha$ and $\bar u_\beta$ they pick out one of the four components of these Dirac bispinors.

> What is the meaning of the subscript $\alpha\beta$ on the matrix?

The $\alpha$ picks out one of the four rows and the $\beta$ picks out one of the four columns, so together they pick out an element of the matrix.

> Does that turn it into a Kronecker matrix?

No. A Kronecker delta has four, not two, ones on the diagonal.

Comment: You wrote, "they pick out one of the four components of these Dirac bispinors."  Since we are in the rest frame, I believe these only have two available components each.  I thought $s$ tells us which one we use.  Don't the two rest frame degree of freedom correspond to the two degrees of freedom: spin up and spin down?  This is exactly the issue which was confusing me.  Thanks!

Comment: A Dirac bispinor has four components in every frame. Some may be zero.

Comment: $s$ doesn’t pick out a component of the bispinor. It specifies which of the two possible bispinors for a particular momentum you’re talking about.

Comment: Yes, G. Smith.  Ones that are zero are not "available."  Furthermore, $s$ certainly does  pick out the components.  If we have $u(p,s)=\left(\begin{matrix}u_1\\u_2\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)$ then $u(p,s_1)=\left(\begin{matrix}u_1\\0\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $u(p,s_2):=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\u_2\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)$.  I think these are called "eigenspinors."  Would you please edit your answer?  I am sure you are wrong.

Comment: That is the wrong way to think about $s$ because it doesn’t work like that in an arbitrary frame. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spinor#For_particles). The notation is for an arbitrary Lorentz frame.

Comment: $s$ takes only two values, and is summed over in your identity; $\alpha$ and $\beta$ take four, as is obvious from the matrix on the right, and are not summed over. I will not be editing my answer because it is correct.

Comment: When I say that the notation is for an arbitrary Lorentz frame, I’m talking about the notation for the two bispinors. I don’t mean that that particular identity holds in every frame.

Comment: I put "rest frame" in the title of my post so you seem to be missing the point, and Zee clearly states that these are only rest frame identities.  If it wasn't a rest frame identity, then how could $\sum u\bar u$ not depend on $p_i$?  Clearly, there is an error in your thinking.  Also, your suggestion that $s$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$ all sum over the same thing is incomprehensible to me.  Are you making a trole by writing the wrong thing on purpose?  Could you just add a space to your answer or something?  I want to take away my upvote but it says it is locked pending an edit.

Comment: You are claiming nonsense that I never said. We don’t seem to be able to communicate, and I’m seeing the message to avoid an extended discussion, so I’m not going to continue. I suggest that you try to understand the Wikipedia article since you have not understood my answer.

Comment: I suggest you notice that the wikipedia article you cite does not use the subscript notation on spinors which is the object of my inquiry.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer so that you can remove your upvote and downvote instead.

Comment: I would downvote if I was sure you were wrong, but I just want to take away the upvote because I didn't understand.  However, it think I'm starting to get it in the last moment.  You mean that $u_\alpha$ is a scalar (which makes sense), not a linearly independent bispinor which is what I thought you meant, and that the $\alpha,\beta$ on the right tell you which matrix element the sum is equal to for a given $\alpha,\beta$ on the left.  Did I get it now?  I will check and re-upvote if I understood now.